# Html table with fixed header and vertical scrollbars on the table body

Tags: html, css

My pen:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/qHDFB

I would like to create a html table:

- With a header that stays fixed
- A table body that shows scrollbars
- The height should NOT have a fixed pixel height it should have 100% height.
- The header cells should be aligned to the row cells. I mention this because often I have seen solutions where column1 enters the horizontally the area of header2. This looks bad.
- Its ok for me when the columns have a percentage width but not pixel because that would not be responsive.
- performance plays no role it will show max 16 rows appr. with max 7 columns.

I want to use CSS only.

It should work in IE10+ and latest FF/Chrome.

You can also use the new CSS Grid Layout from Microsoft which will be ported over to webkit etc... with -ms-grid etc...

How can I make the above individual sample work that the header stays fixed and and the body of the table has vertical scrollbars not the html body itself?

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>First</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Second</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Third</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>                  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

td{
  width:33%;
  border:black solid 1px;
}

tbody{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

tr td{
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
}

th{
  background:lightgray;
  padding:10px;
  border:black solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can a `div` wrap the table, and the div have a fixed height? Otherwise, I don't see how you can use scrollbars while giving it 100% height.

Comment: That would not be according to my needs. You can assume this: A divWrapper has 100% height: inside are 2 divs. The toolbarDiv has 40% height and the tableDiv has 100% height. Inside the tableDiv is the fixed table having rows with a fixed height which should make the whole table also fixed but still stretching to the bottom

Comment: Sorry, previous comment was wrong link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CLaFs

Comment: In IE10 and Chrome28 the top arrow of the vertical scrollbar is not visible or partly visible AND the header cells should be aligned with the row cells which is not the case in your changed sample. (check this out (see the first table) http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html I have also updated my question and yes this is not an easy one ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, you'll run into two problems with an all-in-table-approach: 1) Not having the same width of `<th>`s and `<td>`s because you'll never exactly know the width of the scrollbar in `tbody`. 2) Not being able to have a scrollbar taking the full height of `tbody`. I think @ChrisRockwell 's approach with separating the table headers as pseudo headers from the rest of the table is better and you'd get a scrollbar of full viewport width, that'd just scroll `tbody`. My non-working approach: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aFpdC

Comment: @VolkerE. But ChrisRockwells codepen is buggy see my comment above.

Comment: So I guess I will have to take a javascript/jquery solution where everything is calculated so my requirements are met?

Comment: Like @VolkerE. already stated, the issue I'm having with this is the scrollbar.  I've created a new pen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HELim which uses negative `margin` to put the headers where they belong.  With JavaScript, you can calculate the height of the fixed position header, and the width of the scrollbar, and make adjustments.  Atleast you got me to play around with Grid Layout, which is going to be awesome once fully adopted.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Yes grid layout rocks. Sadly it does not solve the table fix header/scroll problem but I have another idea in my mind...

Comment: @ChrisRockwell I went now with datatables jquery plugin it has a fixed header plugin AND if the datatables parent resizes the table resizes too just what I needed and is not implemented in the jquery plugin fixed header table jquery plugin.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33075195/435605

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this what you're looking for? - http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Just view the source of the example, and this should get you going.

Comment: One of the requirements is `100% height`. Your solution has a fixed height. No good.

Answer (score -2):

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div>First</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div>Second</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div>Third</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>Third</td>
                </tr>                  
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to add something else? Code-only answers are not well received here. You should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solves 
the problem.

Comment: This appears to have been posted before any answer was made